# Deploy Infrastructure via Terraform Modules in Azure Devops

Tags: azure-devops, terraform, terraform-modules

I need to deploy Az Infrastructure by calling modules which are in an ADO project dedicated to TF modules. Each repository in the project represents one Az resource (module). I want to consume them from another projects in the same org. However, I am not able to connect. I tried

```
- script: |  
  git config --global url."https://$SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN@dev.azure.com".insteadOf "[https://<<org>>@dev.azure.com](https://<<org>>@dev.azure.com)"  

  displayName: ''  

  env:
    SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN: $(System.AccessToken)
```

It still doesn't work. I do not want to use ssh and pat. Can't use repository resource as well since there are more than 30 modules. Is there any other way?

Can this new feature be used if I give managed identity access to the agent and give it access to the module project.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/service-principal-managed-identity?view=azure-devops

I still get an error that repository az_key_vault could not be found

Comment: have you tried the suggestion below and if it works for you?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to consume repos in other projects but in the same organization, you can use inline syntax checkout.

```
steps:
- checkout: git://MyProject/MyRepo # Azure Repos Git repository in the same organization
```

For example,

```
trigger:
- none

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- checkout: git://project2/TestPR
- checkout: git://project2/TestTrigger
```

At the same time, you need to add the Build Service account of the project where you run the pipeline to the Contributor group of the projects which hold your repos. For example, I run the pipeline in Project1. If I want to checkout the repos in Project2, I need to add `project1 Build Service (Org name)` as a contributor in Project2.
[image]

See the detailed info about checkout from [Check out multiple repositories in your pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/multi-repo-checkout?view=azure-devops)